# Jest get total line coverage (for gitlab badge)

Tags: jestjs, gitlab, code-coverage

I have seen that you could use GitLab to [generate a badge icon](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pipelines/settings.md#test-coverage-report-badge) on the fly for code coverage. Therefore, in one of the CI jobs, there must be [a regex pattern found](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pipelines/settings.md#test-coverage-parsing).

I have a react project that uses jest for testing. I see that you could use the `--coverage` parameter, this outputs the following:

```
 PASS  __tests__/App-test.js
  ✓ renders correctly (631ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 App.js   |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                36 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.46s
Ran all test suites.
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't provide me with a total number that I could use to satisfy GitLab's regex pattern.

My googling gave me no conclusion on how to output a total coverage percentage.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I knew from other testing libraries as "total coverage" is generally speaking the "total **line** coverage". Thus jest already provides this information in the first row (`All files`), under the column `% Lines`.

Regex could be for detection:

```
All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)
```

Comment: So what did you do to get GitLab to take it and give you the badge?

Comment: Haven't access to the project anymore. I guess I just added a custom regex to GitLab, check this: https://regexr.com/5ebua
Regex: `All files\s*\|\s*[\d\.]*\s*\|\s*[\d\.]*\s*\|\s*[\d\.]*\s*\|\s*([\d\.]*)\s*\|` (I am not a regex expert :D)